# How do I cover/repair this piece of my bath tub?

Tags: bathroom, bathtub

See the attached pictures. I'm short on ideas how to cover or replace this piece. I can't afford a full tub replacement right now so that is out of the question. Thanks

[image: Angle 1]

[image: Angle 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like someone slapped wood on it (with tape???) and the inevitable happened.

What I would do is pry the wood off and install a piece of PVC trim or planking (gluing would be the best option here but be sure to get one that supports vinyl), then use a siliconized latex caulk to seal it up.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the direction I will go with this. Just needed a visualization of the parts required.

Answer (score 0):

Your wet wall should have extended a few inches past the face of your tub. My recommendation is to do just that.